# Combining columns, update columns based on other df, fill NAs

Tags: r, merge, dplyr

at the beginning I'd like to note that I found multiple solutions on SO but none of them met my expectations.

I have to DF's:

**1.**

```
E                           F              G        H
chr1_100203723_100203724    NA             NA       NA
chr1_100212951_100212952    rs760764323    A,G,     0.000008,0.999992,
chr1_10032235_10032236      NA             NA       NA
chr1_100327060_100327061    NA             NA       NA
chr1_100346889_100346890    NA             NA       NA
chr1_100347237_100347238    rs749372877    C,G,T,   0.000008,0.000008,0.999983,
chr1_100357190_100357191    NA             NA       NA
chr1_100358057_100358058    NA             NA       NA
chr2_182852606_182852607    NA             NA       NA
chr2_202492077_202492078    NA             NA       NA
chr2_203760838_203760839    NA             NA       NA
chr2_215976351_215976352    NA             NA       NA
chr2_220354644_220354645    NA             NA       NA
chr2_234749403_234749404    NA             NA       NA
chr2_11802110_11802111      NA             NA       NA
chr2_31167747_31167748      NA             NA       NA
```

**2.**

```
E                           F               G       H
chr1_100203723_100203724    NA              NA      NA
chr1_100212951_100212952    NA              NA      NA
chr1_10032235_10032236      NA              NA      NA
chr1_100327060_100327061    NA              NA      NA
chr1_100346889_100346890    NA              NA      NA
chr1_100347237_100347238    NA              NA      NA
chr1_100357190_100357191    NA              NA      NA
chr1_100358057_100358058    NA              NA      NA
chr2_182852606_182852607    rs773426830     C,T,    0.999967,0.000033,
chr2_202492077_202492078    rs750583431     C,G,    0.000013,0.999987,
chr2_203760838_203760839    NA              NA      NA
chr2_215976351_215976352    rs113648834     C,T,    0.999934,0.000066,
chr2_220354644_220354645    NA              NA      NA
chr2_234749403_234749404    NA              NA      NA
chr2_11802110_11802111      rs371327070     A,G,    0.000044,0.999956,
chr2_31167747_31167748      rs201375957     A,C,T,  0.000008,0.999887,0.000105,
```

**Desired output:**

```
E                           F               G       H
chr1_100203723_100203724    NA              NA      NA
chr1_100212951_100212952    rs760764323     A,G,    0.000008,0.999992,
chr1_10032235_10032236      NA              NA      NA
chr1_100327060_100327061    NA              NA      NA
chr1_100346889_100346890    NA              NA      NA
chr1_100347237_100347238    rs749372877     C,G,T,  0.000008,0.000008,0.999983,
chr1_100357190_100357191    NA              NA      NA
chr1_100358057_100358058    NA              NA      NA
chr2_182852606_182852607    rs773426830     C,T,    0.999967,0.000033,
chr2_202492077_202492078    rs750583431     C,G,    0.000013,0.999987,
chr2_203760838_203760839    NA              NA      NA
chr2_215976351_215976352    rs113648834     C,T,    0.999934,0.000066,
chr2_220354644_220354645    NA              NA      NA
chr2_234749403_234749404    NA              NA      NA
chr2_11802110_11802111      rs371327070     A,G,    0.000044,0.999956,
chr2_31167747_31167748      rs201375957     A,C,T,  0.000008,0.999887,0.000105,
```

As you see DF1 is updated by DF2 columns F, G, H, where column E is my unique index. I tried to do `merge()` but this function didin't update my rows, it jus added columns of DF2 to DF1. I also tried updating with `data.table` and `tidyverse`, and my rows have been updated but other ones went to `NAs`... Finally I decided to do simple `lapply()` with nested `ifelse()`, however I don't know how to update all three columns simultaneously, what is more this is terrible slow for my over 50000 rows of data in each DF...

What I did so far:

```
DF1$F <- sapply(1:nrow(DF1), function(i) ifelse(DF1[i,1]==DF2[i,1] & is.na(DF1[i,1]), DF2[i,1], DF[i,1]))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cand do this in base R:

```
as.data.frame(Map(function(x,y) ifelse(is.na(x),y,x),DF1,DF2))
```

with library `purrr` you can have a prettier more compact form (see Soto's answer for an even more compact one with `dplyr`):

```
library(purrr)
map2_df(DF1,DF2,~ifelse(is.na(.x),.y,.x))
```

In both cases (technically a `data.frame` in the first case and a `tibble` in the second case):

**output**

```
                            E           F      G                           H
1    chr1_100203723_100203724        <NA>   <NA>                        <NA>
2    chr1_100212951_100212952 rs760764323   A,G,          0.000008,0.999992,
3    chr1_10032235_10032236        <NA>   <NA>                        <NA>
4    chr1_100327060_100327061        <NA>   <NA>                        <NA>
5    chr1_100346889_100346890        <NA>   <NA>                        <NA>
6    chr1_100347237_100347238 rs749372877 C,G,T, 0.000008,0.000008,0.999983,
7    chr1_100357190_100357191        <NA>   <NA>                        <NA>
8    chr1_100358057_100358058        <NA>   <NA>                        <NA>
9    chr2_182852606_182852607 rs773426830   C,T,          0.999967,0.000033,
10   chr2_202492077_202492078 rs750583431   C,G,          0.000013,0.999987,
11   chr2_203760838_203760839        <NA>   <NA>                        <NA>
12   chr2_215976351_215976352 rs113648834   C,T,          0.999934,0.000066,
13   chr2_220354644_220354645        <NA>   <NA>                        <NA>
14   chr2_234749403_234749404        <NA>   <NA>                        <NA>
15   chr2_11802110_11802111 rs371327070   A,G,          0.000044,0.999956,
16   chr2_31167747_31167748 rs201375957 A,C,T, 0.000008,0.999887,0.000105,
```

**data**

```
DF1 <- read.table(text="E                           F              G        H
chr1_100203723_100203724    NA             NA       NA
chr1_100212951_100212952    rs760764323    A,G,     0.000008,0.999992,
chr1_10032235_10032236      NA             NA       NA
chr1_100327060_100327061    NA             NA       NA
chr1_100346889_100346890    NA             NA       NA
chr1_100347237_100347238    rs749372877    C,G,T,   0.000008,0.000008,0.999983,
chr1_100357190_100357191    NA             NA       NA
chr1_100358057_100358058    NA             NA       NA
chr2_182852606_182852607    NA             NA       NA
chr2_202492077_202492078    NA             NA       NA
chr2_203760838_203760839    NA             NA       NA
chr2_215976351_215976352    NA             NA       NA
chr2_220354644_220354645    NA             NA       NA
chr2_234749403_234749404    NA             NA       NA
chr2_11802110_11802111      NA             NA       NA
chr2_31167747_31167748      NA             NA       NA",header=T,stringsAsFactors=F)


DF2 <- read.table(text="E                           F               G       H
chr1_100203723_100203724    NA              NA      NA
chr1_100212951_100212952    NA              NA      NA
chr1_10032235_10032236      NA              NA      NA
chr1_100327060_100327061    NA              NA      NA
chr1_100346889_100346890    NA              NA      NA
chr1_100347237_100347238    NA              NA      NA
chr1_100357190_100357191    NA              NA      NA
chr1_100358057_100358058    NA              NA      NA
chr2_182852606_182852607    rs773426830     C,T,    0.999967,0.000033,
chr2_202492077_202492078    rs750583431     C,G,    0.000013,0.999987,
chr2_203760838_203760839    NA              NA      NA
chr2_215976351_215976352    rs113648834     C,T,    0.999934,0.000066,
chr2_220354644_220354645    NA              NA      NA
chr2_234749403_234749404    NA              NA      NA
chr2_11802110_11802111      rs371327070     A,G,    0.000044,0.999956,
chr2_31167747_31167748      rs201375957     A,C,T,  0.000008,0.999887,0.000105,",header=T,stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Comment: I always wondered what is the difference between `Map()` and `mapply()`. Could you shed some light on this?

Comment: In `?Map` you can read `Map is a simple wrapper to mapply which does not attempt to simplify the result` . In my example `mapply` would have returned a `matrix`, and `Map` returned a list, that I converted to a `data.frame`

Answer (score 4):

The function `coalesce` from `dplyr` does exactly that. I m sure we can use `purrr` functions to map the 2 data frames, but here is one using base R `mapply`,

```
DF1[-1] <- mapply(dplyr::coalesce, DF1[-1], DF2[-1])
```

which gives,

> ```
>                          E           F      G                           H
> 1  chr1_100203723_100203724        <NA>   <NA>                        <NA>
> 2  chr1_100212951_100212952 rs760764323   A,G,          0.000008,0.999992,
> 3    chr1_10032235_10032236        <NA>   <NA>                        <NA>
> 4  chr1_100327060_100327061        <NA>   <NA>                        <NA>
> 5  chr1_100346889_100346890        <NA>   <NA>                        <NA>
> 6  chr1_100347237_100347238 rs749372877 C,G,T, 0.000008,0.000008,0.999983,
> 7  chr1_100357190_100357191        <NA>   <NA>                        <NA>
> 8  chr1_100358057_100358058        <NA>   <NA>                        <NA>
> 9  chr2_182852606_182852607 rs773426830   C,T,          0.999967,0.000033,
> 10 chr2_202492077_202492078 rs750583431   C,G,          0.000013,0.999987,
> 11 chr2_203760838_203760839        <NA>   <NA>                        <NA>
> 12 chr2_215976351_215976352 rs113648834   C,T,          0.999934,0.000066,
> 13 chr2_220354644_220354645        <NA>   <NA>                        <NA>
> 14 chr2_234749403_234749404        <NA>   <NA>                        <NA>
> 15   chr2_11802110_11802111 rs371327070   A,G,          0.000044,0.999956,
> 16   chr2_31167747_31167748 rs201375957 A,C,T, 0.000008,0.999887,0.000105,
> ```

**NOTE:** As mentioned by @Moody_Mudskipper, the `purrr` version, which produces a new data frame without altering `DF1` or `DF2`, would be,

```
library(purrr)

map2_df(DF1,DF2,dplyr::coalesce)
```

Comment: neat, with `purrr` it would be just `map2_df(DF1,DF2,coalesce)` and you avoid the trick to get a `data.frame` and can keep `DF1` intact

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper ahh...thanks. I was doing `map2_df(DF1, DF2, ~coalesce)`

Comment: `map2_df(DF1, DF2, ~coalesce(.x,.y)) ` then :)

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper hehe yeah, I just figured it out :)

Comment: As you se there are 2 chromosomes (simple part of data), I have all of them to combine together. In other words I combined df1 and df2 and than I'd like to add df3, df4 to file df1 (with already updated rows by df2). Can I do this and it won't provide any mistakes in data? In addition theres no diplicates of E column considering all datasets. I just ask because I'm afraid that there's may be some unwanted update of some row.

Comment: I m not sure I follow. You want to create 2 more data sets that will be exactly the same? (df3, df4)

Answer (score 0):

Another naive way of doing this is using `paste0`

```
> df1 <- data.frame(E = c('A','B','C'), F=c('0.9,1',NA,NA), G=c(NA,'0.98,0.34',NA), H=c(NA,'0.98,0.34',NA), stringsAsFactors = F)
> df2 <- data.frame(E = c('A','B','C'), F=c(NA,'1,3',NA), G=c(NA,NA,'5,6,7'), H=c(NA,NA,NA), stringsAsFactors = F)



    > df1[is.na(df1)] <- ''
    > df2[is.na(df2)] <- ''
    > 
    > mapply(paste, df1[-1], df2[-1])
     F        G            H           
[1,] "0.9,1 " " "          " "         
[2,] " 1,3"   "0.98,0.34 " "0.98,0.34 "
[3,] " "      " 5,6,7"     " "
```

Updated Based on [Sotos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5635580/sotos) suggestion with `mapply`

Comment: Isn't it a merge with categorical data?

Comment: If you have 100 columns, this becomes hideous

Comment: Yes, Thanks I get it, Is it better to remove the answer ?

Comment: Well you could do something like `mapply(paste, df1[-1], df2[-1])`